# fix netbean dependencies

Tags: apt, software-installation, netbeans

```
martin@martin:~$ sudo apt-get install netbeans
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 netbeans : Depends: libnb-apisupport3-java (= 8.1+dfsg3-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libnb-ide14-java (= 8.1+dfsg3-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libnb-java5-java (= 8.1+dfsg3-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When running sudo `apt-get install netbeans` I get error when I try to run

```
martin@martin:~$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java8-installer is already the newest version (8u131-1~webupd8~2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libavcodec57 libavfilter6 libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libchromaprint0 libllvm3.8 libpostproc54 librubberband2v5 libswresample2
  libswscale4 libtidy5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How to fix this error in installing netbeans in ubuntu

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: i did it returns more errors @George

Comment: Can we see the "more errors"?

Comment: @George i was able to fix it it was due to change it apt status file.. now im back to original problem where I cant install.. i have install sypnatic I can see the broken package but it is not installing